# Привязать инпут к ползунку slider-range

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

как сделать, чтобы каждый инпут был над своим ползунком и перемещался вместе с ним?

```js
$("#slider-range").slider({
  range: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  values: [75, 2500],
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#min").val(ui.values[0] + " руб.");
    $("#max").val(ui.values[1] + " руб.");
  }
});
$("#min").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) + " руб.");
$("#max").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1) + " руб.");
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css">
<div id="slider-range"></div>
<input type="text" id="min" readonly>
<input type="text" id="max" readonly>
```

Comment: Если ответ подошел, то предлагаю акцептовать его...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого необходимо в функции `slide(event, ui)` изменять стили инпутов в зависимости от того что тянется, например изменять отступ в зависимости от положения слайдера.

```js
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
          range: true,
          min: 0,
          max: 3000,
          values: [ 75, 2500 ],
          slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#min" ).val(ui.values[ 0 ] + " руб.");          
            $( "#max" ).val( ui.values[ 1 ] + " руб." );
          // set style based on touched rangeslider handle
          if (ui.values.indexOf(ui.value) === 0) {
            $( "#min" ).css({
              'left': ui.handle.style.left,
              'z-index': 1,
            });
            $( "#max" ).css({
              'z-index': 0,
            });
          }
          if (ui.values.indexOf(ui.value) === 1) {
            $( "#max" ).css({
              'left': ui.handle.style.left,
              'z-index': 0,
            });
            $( "#min" ).css({
              'z-index': 0,
            });
          } 
          },
          stop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#min" ).val(ui.values[ 0 ] + " руб.");          
            $( "#max" ).val( ui.values[ 1 ] + " руб." );
          // set style based on touched rangeslider handle
          if (ui.values.indexOf(ui.value) === 0) {
            $( "#min" ).css({
              'left': ui.handle.style.left,
              'z-index': 1,
            });
            $( "#max" ).css({
              'z-index': 0,
            });
          }
          if (ui.values.indexOf(ui.value) === 1) {
            $( "#max" ).css({
              'left': ui.handle.style.left,
              'z-index': 0,
            });
            $( "#min" ).css({
              'z-index': 0,
            });
          } 
          }
        });
        $( "#min" ).val($( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + " руб.");
        $( "#max" ).val($( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 )  + " руб.");
```

```css
    #min, #max {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
    }
    #min {
      left: 4%;
    }
    #max {
      left: 82.5%
    }
```

```html
 

      
    
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css">
            <div id="slider-range"></div>
                  <input type="text" id="min" readonly >
                  <input type="text" id="max" readonly >
```

Comment: правый инпут скачет

Comment: Стартовую позицию инпутов можно изменить как угодно, например в зависимости от позиции высчитывать при загрузке страницы...

Comment: А если "скачет" было про клик на слайдере -- то надо было добавить [функцию stop](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-stop). Обновил код в ответе